# conda install -c bioconda simlord | UnsatisfiedError

Tags: 18.04, python, anaconda, conda

Following this [tutorial](https://bitbucket.org/genomeinformatics/simlord/src/master/) and two [installation steps](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/simlord), I want to run `SimLoRD`.

On `Ubuntu 18.04`, using a `Python 3.9` venv:

```
conda install -c bioconda simlord
UnsatisfiedError
```

[Terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgiIb.png)

I have tried this on `Windows` and `Linux` with different versions of `Anaconda` and `Python` without luck.

---

Suggested `pip install simlord==1.0.4` via. `Windows 10`:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

[Windows pip install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9Hwx.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please do not have pictures of text. Always include all text in the body of the questions. Pictures do not help.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution at BioStars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9463133/#9463299). TLDR; `Python 3.6.5` is the most recent stable version for installing and running `SimLoRD`